# Aggregating list in sql server from 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables where Table Task is formatted like such:

```
Task_id  | taskname
1        | create  
2        | move
3        | add
4        | subtract
```

where Task_id is numeric and taskname is ntext

Table task_user:

```
Task_id  | User_id
1        | 1
1        | 2
2        | 1
2        | 3
3        | 4
3        | 5
4        | 6
```

Where both task_id and user_id are of numeric data type
Table users:

```
  User_id  | Username
  1       | joe
  2       | bob
  3       | karen
  4       | ann
  5       | tommy
  6       | gary
```

Where username is of type nvarchar
  And I want to write a query that generates the following:

```
taskname   | Members
create     | joe, bob
move       | joe, karen
add        | ann, tommy
subtract   | gary
```

So far I've managed to connect the task_id with the user_id's using the following query:

```
SELECT task_id , STUFF(( SELECT  ','+ convert(varchar(50), user_id) FROM task_user
WHERE task.task_id = task_user.task_id FOR XML PATH('')),1 ,1, '')  Members
FROM task
GROUP BY task_id;
```

which generates

```
Task_id | Members
1       | 1, 2
2       | 1, 3
3       | 4, 5
4       | 6
```

How would I get it so that Members is grouped by the username itself and not the id?

Comment: You don't want this to be grouped by the name. If you had two people with the same name it would be a problem. I think what you want is to display the name? You would do that with a join.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `join` in the subquery to get the user name:

```
SELECT t.*,
       STUFF( (SELECT  ',' + u.username
               FROM task_user tu JOIN
                    users u
                    ON u.user_id = tu.user_id
               WHERE t.task_id = tu.task_id FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            )  Members
FROM task t;
```

I don't think the `GROUP BY` is needed in the outer query.